# Rolling Dice Histogram

Tags: c, generator, histogram, dice

Hello I have written the code needed for a dice rolling generator base on rand() and time.h.
It basically asks the user to input the number of times he wants the dice to be rolled and then rolls those X times. It saves the times each one of 1-6 number was rolled in an array and the percentage of each number in another array.

Now what I want to do is create a histogram the has the numbers 1-6 and - on the X-axis, the percentages and | on the Y-axis and stars(*) for columns.

Something like this:

```
10% | *
 8% |* * *
 6% |* * * * *
 4% |* * * * * *
 2% |* * * * * *
    +------------
     1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I have search throught google to find something to begin with but I have really found anything similar to my case thats gonna help me begin with.

My code thus for is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random_number();
float calc_percentage(int totals, int nums);
float calc_maxper(float perc[6]);
float calc_minper(float perc[6]);
float permin;
float permax;


int main(void)
{
  int nums;
  int i;
  int totals[6] = {0};
  float percentages[6] = {0};

  srand(time(NULL));

  printf("How many numbers to generate?");
  scanf("%d", &nums);

  for (i = 1; i <= nums; i++)
  {
    int x = random_number();
    totals[x-1]++;
  }

  for (i = 0; i<6; i++)
  {
    percentages[i] = calc_percentage(totals[i],nums);
    printf("The percentage of each number is: %.2f%\n", percentages[i]);
  }


  permin = calc_minper(percentages);
  permax = calc_maxper(percentages);

  if (((permax) - (permin)) > 5)
    printf("The generator is not good.\n");
  printf("The percentage difference is:%.1f\n", permax-permin);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}



int random_number()
{
  int randnum;
  randnum = 1 + (rand() % 6);

  return randnum;
}

float calc_percentage(int totals, int numbers)
{
  float a;

  a = (totals * 100)/numbers;

  return a;
}

float calc_minper(float perc[6])
{
  int i;
  float min;
  min = perc[0];

  for (i=1; i<6; i++)
  {
    if (perc[i] < min)
      min = perc[i];
  }
  return min;
}

float calc_maxper(float perc[6])
{
  int i;
  float max;
  max = perc[0];

  for (i=1; i<6; i++)
  {
    if (perc[i] > max)
      max = perc[i];
  }
  return max;
}
```

Ok I finally got this done.

Kinda long and messy but it definitely gets the job done!!

```
printf("20%|");
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    if (percentages[i] >= 20)
       printf("* ");
}
printf("\n");

printf("16%|");
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    if (percentages[i] >= 16)
       printf("* ");
}  
printf("\n");


printf("12%|");
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    if (percentages[i] >= 12)
       printf("* ");
}  
printf("\n");


printf(" 8%|");
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    if (percentages[i] >= 8)
       printf("* ");
}  
printf("\n");


printf(" 4%|");
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    if (percentages[i] >= 4)
       printf("* ");
}  



printf("\n");
printf("  +------------\n");   
printf("   1 2 3 4 5 6\n");
```

Thanks dude for your ideas!!
If u have any quick ideas to make it shorter am all ears!

Comment: Where exactly do you get stucked? BTW: homework?

Comment: Instead of debugging your whole code, could you direct us - what is the problem with the current solution, what is the current output, etc.?

Comment: Your calc_percentage function returns a int casted to float. Force floating point operations by using 100.0 instead of 100.

Answer (score 1):

For each range (10%, 8%, etc), check if the current dice number (1-6) percentage exceeds it, then print a * (or a space if it doesn't meet the range minimum). At the end, print the graph base.

You could use a for to handle the ranges:

```
float range;
float interval = (permax-permin)/(NUM_INTERVALS-1);
for (range = permax; range >= permin - EPSILON; range -= interval){
    int i;
    printf("%2.2f%% | ", range);
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
        char *out = percentages[i] >= range ? "*" : " ";
        printf("%s ", out);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("      | 1 2 3 4 5 6\n");
```

Comment: Nice code man! This is exactly what am looking for.
I have looked at your code but am still trying to figure what each of these variables(interval,NUM_INTERVALS, and EPSILON) mean?

Comment: The interval variable holds the difference between two "ranges". What I called range is actually the range lower limit.

Comment: EPSILON is a define to the floating pointing maximum error, the standard library comes with this. You can define it to 0.00001, without any consequences to your solution.
NUM_INTERVALS is a define that YOU should set, to the number of lines your graph will have. In your example, it should be 5.